# Why I still got error functio at flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Why I still got error functio at flutter?

I'd removed the old function and used new function, but it was still got old function.

In my main.dart, I tried to called LoginScreen

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'yocamp',
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

But it was called MobileScreenLayout

```
home: const ResponsiveLayout(
        mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
        webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
      ),
```

In my LoginScreen

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            //sva image
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/yocampLogo.svg',
              //color: primaryColor,
              height: 64,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 64),
            //text field input for email

            //text field input for password

            //button login
            //Transitioning to singing up
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

in the MobileScreenLayout

```
class MobileScreenLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  const MobileScreenLayout({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Text('This is mobile'),
    ));
  }
}
```

I want to show svg, but it's still show `This is mobile`

where has problems?

Comment: save and hot restart

Comment: reinstall the app